# PDF of the difference of a uniform random variable and an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider two independent random variables $U$ and $X$ based on uniform and exponential distributions, respectively. How can I calculate the PDF of $Z=U-X$ if $U>X$?

Comment: Please share what have you tried. So as to make people who will answer your question understand where you stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U\sim Uniform(a, b)$ and $X\sim Exp(\lambda)$. Then,

$$
\begin{array}{rll}
CDFs: & F_U(u) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & u < a \\
\frac{u-a}{b-a}, & a \leq u \leq b \\
1, & u > b 
\end{array}
\right. & F_X(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & x < 0 \\
1-e^{-\lambda x}, & x \geq 0 
\end{array}
\right. \\
PDFs: & f_U(u) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & u < a \\
\frac{1}{b-a}, & a \leq u \leq b \\
0, & u > b 
\end{array}
\right. & f_X(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & x < 0 \\
\lambda e^{-\lambda x}, & x \geq 0 
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
$$

The first step is to calculate the CDF of $Z = U-X$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
F_Z(z) &= \text{Pr}(Z \leq z) = \text{Pr}(U \leq X+z) = \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty}F_U(x+z)f_X(x)dx = \\
&= \int_z^{+\infty}F_U(y)f_X(y-z)dy = \\
&= \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & z < a \\
\frac{1}{b-a}\int_z^b\lambda e^{-\lambda(y-z)}dy, & a \leq z \leq b \\
\int_z^{+\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda(y-z)}dy, & z > b
\end{array}
\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

The second step is to find a CDF of a truncated $Z$ ($Z > 0$):

$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{Z|Z >0}(z) = \text{Pr}(Z \leq z|Z > 0) = \frac{\text{Pr}(Z \leq z, Z > 0)}{\text{Pr}(Z > 0)} = \frac{\text{Pr}(0 < Z \leq z)}{1 - \text{Pr}(Z \leq 0)} = \frac{F_Z(z) - F_Z(0)}{1-F_Z(0)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Finally,

$$
f_{Z|Z >0}(z) = \frac{d}{dz}F_{Z|Z >0}(z).
$$

So, the key step here is to find $F_Z(z)$ and proceed from that point then.

Answer (score 1):

The pdf is given by convolution

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_U(u)f_X(u-z)du$$

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_U(z+x)f_X(x)dx$$

You integrate the joint pdf after solving one of the variables for Z.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $X \sim Exp(1)$ and $U \sim Unif[0,1]$.

Use the fact that
$F_Z(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(U-X \leq z)=F_{U-X}(z)$. Also remember that $f_{U-X}(z)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f_U(u)f_X(u-z)du}$